# Angular production build minifies the css class names

Tags: angular-cli

I would like to know if Angular provies a way to minify the css/scss using the build process?

The flag which enables me to do that.

Describe alternatives you've considered:
I wonder if it might not be possible when dynamically setting class names using TS variables etc.